# Remove specific shortcode from get_the_content()

Tags: shortcode, the-content

I have a variable like this:

```
$post_content = get_the_content();
```

Here I want to remove some specific shortcode from the $post_content variable e.g I want to remove only this `[video height="300" width="300" mp4="localhost.com/video.mp4"]` all other shortcodes and content formatting should be leaved intact.

How could this be done?

**UPDATE:**

I'm able to remove some specific shortcode by using code something like this ...

```
<?php 
    echo do_shortcode( 
        str_replace(
            '[video height="300" width="300" mp4="localhost.com/video.mp4"]', 
            '', 
            get_the_content()
        ) 
    ); 
?>
```

But it is also removing all html tags/formatting of `get_the_content()`. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 4):

If you want exactly this shortcode:

```
[video height="300" width="300" mp4="localhost.com/video.mp4"]
```

to output nothing, then you can use the `wp_video_shortcode_override` filter or the `wp_video_shortcode` filter to achieve that.

Here are two such examples:

### Example #1

```
/**
 * Let the [video] shortcode output "almost" nothing (just a single space) for specific attributes
 */
add_filter( 'wp_video_shortcode_override', function ( $output, $attr, $content, $instance )
{  
    // Match specific attributes and values
    if( 
          isset( $atts['height'] ) 
        && 300 == $atts['height'] 
        && isset( $atts['width'] ) 
        && 400 == $atts['width'] 
        && isset( $atts['mp4'] )
        && 'localhost.com/video.mp4' == $atts['mp4']   
    )
        $output = ' '; // Must not be empty to override the output

    return $output;
}, 10, 4 );
```

### Example #2

```
/**
 * Let the [video] shortcode output nothing for specific attributes
 */
add_filter( 'wp_video_shortcode', function( $output, $atts, $video, $post_id, $library )
{
    // Match specific attributes and values
    if( 
          isset( $atts['height'] ) 
        && 300 == $atts['height'] 
        && isset( $atts['width'] ) 
        && 400 == $atts['width'] 
        && isset( $atts['mp4'] )
        && 'localhost.com/video.mp4' == $atts['mp4']   
    )
        $output = '';

    return $output;
}, 10, 5 );
```

### Note

I would recommend the first example, because there we are intercepting it early on and don't need to run all the code within the shortcode callback.

Comment: Nice approach. :-)

Comment: let's hope it works, since I must admit I didn't test it ;-) @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 1):

You can use php **[preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)** core function to search for your shortcode in content and remove it so your code may be :

```
$post_content_without_shortcodes = preg_replace ( '/\[video(.*?)\]/s' , '' , get_the_content() );
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me remove a broken shortcode from the content that was carried over through an import.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be

```
$post_content_without_shortcodes = strip_shortcodes(get_the_content());
```

or there's also

```
$post_content_without_shortcodes = remove_all_shortcodes(get_the_content());
```

Comment: No, i dont want to remove all shortcodes from the content. Just want to remove some specific shortcode having specific attributes. e.g i want to remove only this `[video height="300" width="300" mp4="localhost.com/video.mp4"]` all other shortcodes and content formatting should be leaved intact.